# MySQL Query for recent n days post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an sql Table say `Data` which has a column `posttime` with default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in `YY-MM-DD H-M-S`. It also has another column "Days" where N number of days is given.

I have another PHP page which gets the data from the SQL table. I want to use time() function and display only those results which are still not N days after Posttime date.

```
Eg- If Row1- PostTime date is 2017-05-1 03:09:09, Days is 3 days
       Row2- PostTime date is 2017-05-1 03:09:09, Days is 2 days
       User date- 2017-05-4 03:09:09
```

Then output should be row 1 onl.

Thanks for any help and sorry for any troubles since I'm still not fully proficient in SQL

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899422/loop-in-column-name-mysql#comment74832686_43899422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.posttime > date_add(now(), interval t.days day)
```